# python independent hash input

Tags: python, hash, md5

I am trying to use md5 as a key stream generator and I need the inputs and the corresponding hash values to be independent of one another. my problem is the following:

```
from hashlib import md5
a1=md5()
a2=md5()
a1.update(b'a')
a1.update(b'b')
a2.update(b'ab')
a1.digest()==a2.digest()
True
```

from above, what I actually want is for a1.update(b'b') to be hash value of 'b' not 'ab'. in another words what I would want is to concatenate the hash values to form a key stream. for example I have a seed as: "TEST" and I want to feed each letter to the md5 and in simple terms have the result of md5('T')+md5('E')+md5('S')+md4('T'). I might have thought that the following function would work

```
def keygen(key):
    a = md5()
    keystream=bytearray(b'')
    for i in key:
        a.update(i.encode())
        keystream += a.digest()
    return keystream
```

But since a.update(a); a.update(b) is equivalent to a.update(a+b) it doesn't lead to the results I desire. 
I found no method to clear the instance to achieve independent results. On the other hand I cannot instantiate new objects per loop to achieve the goal I want. 
How can I reach my desired goal considering above.
thank you all.

Comment: Why couldn't you instantiate new object? Just move `a = md5()` inside the loop.

Comment: I am new to programming, Since I might have needed thousands of distinct inputs for md5 hash function, I though from the memory complexity perspective it would not be a good Idea, No I get it, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't clear an existing instance, but you don't need to, either.

Just instantiate a new one:

```
def keygen(key):
    keystream=bytearray(b'')
    for i in key:
        a = md5(i.encode())
        keystream += a.digest()
    return keystream
```

---

Now, please bear in mind that what you're trying to do is **terribly insecure**, because it is trivial to derive the original key from the computed keystream, which is a very undesirable property for a PRNG (although this isn't even a PRNG because the keystream is finite).

Usual warnings apply: don't roll your own crypto unless you're just playing around or learning.

Comment: thank you Thomas, What I have in mind as the seed is a 100 character string randomly ordered and the hash inputs are distinc each time considering the permutations done on the string to make the feed ready. this keystream is about to be XORed with a data and |keystream| = |Data|. considering the 100! ways of forming the first seed I think it can be some how reliable